android java: share video from other app into my app causes an exception
I share a video from Whatsapp chat to my app and get the video uri into videoUri. Then I try to do this:
try {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(context, videoUri);
    retriever.release();
}
catch (Exception e) {}

and it reaches the exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
(videoUri: content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/b21943fd-edc1-40a4-98a8-d8f21e101da5)
How to solve it? (I want the app to access whatsapp videos)
When the video is shared from the Gallery, it works fine.
